# (C#) Need help with Shuffling a list

Tags: unity, c#

I'm making a deck building game in Unity and need a way to shuffle a deck of cards in a list.

I've tried to use a version of the Fisher Yates Shuffle, but It's not working. I'm not given any errors, the game just doesn't do anything when I try to use the function.

This is the code I'm working with.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Deck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Card> AbilityDeck;


    public void ShuffleDeck()
    {
        Shuffle(AbilityDeck);
    }

    public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)
    {
        System.Random random = new System.Random();
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n < 1)
        {
            int k = random.Next(n);
            n--;
            T temp = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on your shuffle method and traced in the code to see if it does what you think it should?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop condition is `while (n < 1)`.

Since `n` is integer and initialized to `IList<T>.Count`, which – on a good implementation – can't be negative. It means that the only value of `n` that satisfies the condition `(n < 1)` is `0`.

That means that it will only enter the loop when the list is empty (`n = 0`). And in that case there is nothing to shuffle, isn't it?

Thus, the code does nothing.

---

I searched for a similar implementation of Fisher-Yates shuffle and found this one:

```
int n = list.Count;  
while (n > 1) {  
    n--;  
    int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
    T value = list[k];  
    list[k] = list[n];  
    list[n] = value;  
}
```

Source: [Randomize a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thank you!